# How do I change the XXX in "no-reply@salesforce in behalf of XXX" In Salesforce

Tags: apex, user-admin

I have job scheduled which parses an XML coming into salesforce from another system and it creates records in salesforce by reading the XML file.After this process happens there is an email sent out to some users that the process have finished. There is code which sets the to address in SingleEmailMessage object and the body of the email. This email is sent by  "no-reply@salesforce in behalf of XXX". XXX has a name which I would like to replace wit another name. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

mail.setReplyTo('support@acme.com')
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008xhKIAQ